# How can I render a watermark image in my highchart from local directory?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have an image that I would like to render as a watermark on my chart. I saw the documentation of the official highcharts website regarding the `Renderer.image` method but that only concerns an external resource. Is there anyway I can get an image from my `app/assets/images` directory?

Comment: I don't understand about the problems with what you call an external resource. Can you please explain that and why the `Renderer.image` didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an image as a watermark to a chart using `Renderer.image` like this:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.renderer.image('../img/logo.png', 6, 6, 45, 32)
                    .add();
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    exporting: {
        enableImages: true
    }
});
```

Working example here: **http://jsfiddle.net/tLpL98L2/1/**

Notice that the watermark image is JSFiddle's logo which is a relative URL, not an absolute URL.  You don't need to specify `http://` when using the `renderer.image` function so this should let you use images on your own server.